# All permutations of word Python - 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I haver to create all permutations of an input string and remove duplicates, if present. This means I have to shuffle all letters from the input in all possible orders.

```
 File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(sorted(permutations('a')), ['a']);
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My code:

```
import collections

def rotate(l, n):
    rotate = l[-n:] + l[:-n]
def permutations(a):

    d = collections.deque()
    m = d.rotate(len(a))
    
    return m
```

Comment: You return a value with a `return` statement, not by assigning a result to the name of the function. (Which, if memory serves, *is* how Pascal indicated the return value of  a function, but I digress.)

Comment: Also, your `rotate` function isn't used; you are calling the `deque` class's `rotate` method, which modifies `d` in place rather than returning a new rotated deque. Call `d.rotate`, then return `d`.

Comment: And finally, rotating a `deque` *once* doesn't give you all the permutations; it gives you *a* permutation. Even rotating it multiple times would only eventually give you the cyclic permutations of the original sequence.

Comment: @chepner. You make good points. These likely would constitute a good answer.

Comment: You are looking for [multiset_permutations](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html)

Comment: `<module>
    from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'`

It's still doesnt work, do you know why? it is python 3.6~

Comment: `sympy` is not in core Python. You would need to `pip install sympy` at your command prompt.

Comment: Okay Im doing it on codewars and what I see its impossible for using this sympy, but thank you very much anyway for understand that opportunity.
I will try my best to make it by this deque or if you have any other idea it would be lovely..

Comment: @chepner Maybe thats true, but can I use this deque and rotarte function to make all kind of versions of this word? Im trying with for, but still nothing.
Thanks